# Call a public variable using its method ID instead of its function name

Tags: web3.py, python

If I had the method ID but not the name, how would I call it using Web3.py?
Normally, I would use `fContract.functions.functionName().call()` but as I don't have the function name, how would I be able to insert, say, aabbccdd instead of functionName?

Comment: just encode the parameters for the call, and when you have that, put in the frist four bytes of tx.Data() field the signature of the function (which is 4 bytes), then append the encoded (bytes) of the parameters. Thats it!

Answer (score 1):

If you have the contract's abi you could use [get_function_by_selector](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/contracts.html#web3.contract.Contract.get_function_by_selector)

```
unknown_func = contract.get_function_by_selector('0xac37eebb')
unknown_func(param1, param2).call()
```

If you don't have the contract's abi then you can only do as Nulik says encode the parameters into the transaction input data to build the transaction.